# Zendesk API - Compare two fields in query

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

I'm trying to perform a `query` via the Zendesk Search API that compares two fields. E.g. I want to get all tickets where `created_at` is equal to `updated_at`.

This syntax is accepted, but the result is not correct `query=type:ticket created_at:(updated_at)`.

Are such predicates supported by the Zendesk Search API?
If not - are there other endpoints, which can provide me the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything that supports this syntax in the search reference. You would have to query tickets in your preferred time range, or of all time, and assert if the creation and update time indeed match. Here is a sample code on how you do it in python using a Zendesk API wrapper called Zenpy:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from zenpy import Zenpy
from os import environ

load_dotenv()


def main():
    zenpy_client = Zenpy(
        subdomain=environ["SUBDOMAIN"],
        email=environ["EMAIL"],
        token=environ["API_TOKEN"],
    )

    tickets = zenpy_client.tickets.incremental(start_time=1)
    for ticket in tickets:
        if ticket.created_at == ticket.updated_at:
            print(ticket)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code will print the ticket id of any ticket that had no update since creation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason I posted the question is because I wanted to avoid requesting all data by doing multiple requests and then do in-memory filtering.
I will mark the answer as accepted though since this is not supported